# Null check operator used on a null value while using variable from provider into another screen

Tags: flutter

I am using provider for statemanagement. when i call nullable (int? tipIndex) variable using provider in another class i must have to put ! operator... when i put ! opertaor i get error that null check opertaor used on null value... how can i keep my variable null initially.

Here is provider class code :

```
 int? tipIndex;
  List<double> tipList = [2, 3, 5];
```

here i am assigning tipIndex the value of index from ListView.builder

```
setState(() {
               cart.tipIndex = index;
               });
```

here i am using values

```
cart.tipList[index] == cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]
```

here is Complete list View builder

```dart
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: cart.tipList.length,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    return tipContainer(context, cart.tipList[index].toInt(),
        () {
      setState(() {
        cart.tipIndex = index;
      });
    },
        cart.tipList[index] == cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex]
            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 164, 1)
                .withOpacity(0.5)
            : Colors.black54,
        cart.tipList[index] == cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex]
            ? Colors.white
            : Colors.transparent);
  }),
);
```

[Here is UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Eu9O.jpg)

Comment: ,Hafeez, you can use like this from `cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]` to `cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex ?? 0]`, if `tipIndex` is null in any case then it will take 0 index

Comment: @ॐRakeshKumar I tried this but I must have to use null initially.. beacuse giving tip is optional

Comment: Welcome to SO! Most probably the `setState` hasn't executed yet and `cart.tipIndex` is still `null`. One way to fix it is to only build the UI conditionally with `cart.tipIndex != null`

Comment: Thanks... @lepsch setting default value always pick tip from list... I only want to pick tip when user click on any tip amount

Comment: You should then build the UI conditionally. Would you please [edit] your question and copy-paste a bit more code around `cart.tipList[index] == cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]`?

Comment: yes sure i'll edit

Comment: @lepsch I edited the Question please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build the UI conditionally by checking if `cart.tipIndex` is `null` or not before actually using it. It's going to be something as below:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemCount: cart.tipList.length,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
    return tipContainer(
      context,
      cart.tipList[index].toInt(),
      () {
        setState(() {
          cart.tipIndex = index;
        });
      },
      // Here
      cart.tipIndex != null && cart.tipList[index] == cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]
          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 243, 164, 1)
              .withOpacity(0.5)
          : Colors.black54,
      // Here
      cart.tipIndex != null && cart.tipList[index] == cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]
          ? Colors.white
          : Colors.transparent,
    );
  }),
);
```

Comment: in this way i am getting this error The argument type 'int?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'..... when i put ! operator cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!] like this... i Get same error that null check operator used on null value

Comment: That's weird. The part after `&&` should only execute if and only if the part before is `true`. This is called boolean short-circuit: _The logical AND expression is a short-circuit operator. As each operand is converted to a boolean, if the result of one conversion is found to be false, the AND operator stops and returns false; it does not evaluate any of the remaining operands._ Maybe it's another null check operator that is failing now?

Comment: I am thinking the same but unfortunately they are same null check errors... if I remove null check i get "type" error if I put null check I get null check used on null value error

Comment: 1 change appeared after these boolean short-circuit is that now whole screen is red with error "null check operator .............", before these boolean short-circuit only a part of screen was red where I was using ListView.builder

Comment: Can you check the debug output for where the error is being raised?

Comment: Debug console says the same error message that null check operator used on a null value

Comment: Are there any kind of stack-trace?

Comment: ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following _CastError was thrown building Cartscreen(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _CartscreenState#79fbe):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was
Cartscreen
lib/screens/home_screen.dart:23
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _CartscreenState.build
package:operation_falafel/screens/cart_screen.dart:590

Comment: And the line 590 in `screens/cart_screen.dart` is?

Comment: this is on line 590   'AED ${cart.totalAmount + cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]}',

Comment: Text(
                                            
                                          'AED ${cart.totalAmount + cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!]}',
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.white,
                    
                                          ),

Comment: That's it... the error is right there. It should be something like: `Text( 'AED ${cart.totalAmount + (cart.tipIndex != null ? cart.tipList[cart.tipIndex!] : 0)}',`. The same problem you've had before is presented in this line.

Comment: here we go!Thank You sooooooooooooooooooo much.... got my errror resolved...... Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooo  much AGAIN......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246573/discussion-between-usman-hafeez-and-lepsch).